# React Native: Duplicate resources error in latest version

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, duplicates

In latest version of react native (0.71.8) gradle plugin upgraded. So I not able to build release apk(giving duplicate resources error). How to solve this error?

```
doLast {
    def moveFunc = { resSuffix ->
        File originalDir = file("$buildDir/generated/res/react/release/drawable-${resSuffix}");
        if (originalDir.exists()) {
            File destDir = file("$buildDir/../src/main/res/drawable-${resSuffix}");
            ant.move(file: originalDir, tofile: destDir);
        }
    }
    moveFunc.curry("ldpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("mdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("hdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xhdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xxhdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xxxhdpi").call()
}
```

Above solution not working in latest version of React Native.